# How did the two McClanes get to Chernobyl as quickly as the bad guys?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-good-day-to-die-hard

In the later part of [Good Day to Die Hard](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1606378/?ref_=sr_1) the two McClanes steal a car to follow the bad guys. They drive from Moscow to Chernobyl, which is in the middle of the Ukraine, a long way from Moscow.

The bad guys went in a helicopter as far as I can tell. So how did the McClanes get there nearly as fast as the bad guys?

Comment: Movie geography.

Comment: Maybe the bad guys were driving their helicopter the same way that [Johnny English drove "his"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDs5vuzAAyA).

Comment: The distance is close to 600 miles, and would take 12 hours, not accounting for the issue of a heavily guarded international border that needs to be crossed. Epic fail by the movie.

Comment: On top of that they just happened to still have their passports with them and they also happened to have visa's already stamped to allow them to make the crossing from Russia to the Ukraine

Answer (score 3):

I just saw the film. According to a website the two places are 430 miles apart. Even if they averaged 60mph (unlikely) it would have taken over 7 hours. When they get there and are loading up with weapons.